# Get hashtable obj by key & change its public properties

Tags: c#, hashtable

First of all I declare a hashtable and its values. The key of a hashtable entry is a GUID and the value is an object with a few string values.

```
    Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
    Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
    InstallationFiles instFiles = new InstallationFiles(string1, string2, string3);
    hash.Add(g, instFiles);
    //...add many other values with different GUIDs...
```

My goal is to give a user a possibility to EDIT string 1, string2, string3. To cut a long story short, I am in a position where I can get the "GUID g" of the entry which needs to be edited:

```
   public void edit() 
   {
         //here I retrieve the GUID g of the item which has to be edited:
         object objectHash = item.Tag;
         //here i loop through all hash entries to find the editable one:
         foreach(DictionaryEntry de in hash)
         {
            if(de.Key.ToString() == objectHash) 
            {
            //here I would like to access the selected entry and change string1 - 
           //the line below is not working.

            hash[de.Key].string1 = "my new value"; 
            }
         }

   }
```

How do I make this line work?

```
    hash[de.Key].string1 = "my new value";
```

Comment: Use ``Dictionary<Guid, InstallationFiles>`` to get strongly type variable and access its properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Dictionary<Guid, InstallationFiles>` instead `HashTable`

upd. You can use this.

```
 (hash[de.Key] as InstallationFiles).string1 = "asdasd"
```

Ok, explanation:

Because Hashtable is not generic type, it contains references on keys and values as Objects.

Thats why, when you access to your value `hashtable[mykey]`, you got reference to `Object`. To make it as reference to your type (`InstallationFiles`), you have to from "reference to `Object`" get "reference to `InstallationFiles`". Im my sample I use "`as`" operator to do this.

Comment: My boss wants me to use Hashtable. I can't make it work with Hashtable at all?

Comment: So, ```(hash[de.Key] as InstallationFiles).string1 = "asdasd"```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I will try to use Dictionary next time.

Comment: While this is certainly good advice, it is not at all an answer to the question.  This is something that should be posted as a comment.

Comment: @Servy Hi, Servy. I updated my answer. Hope it looks like answer now.